# Rolling a die until the sequence $65656$ shows up

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Assume we want to model the game where we roll a die until the sequence $65656$ shows up using **Markov chains.**

Assume the state space $\mathbb{X} = \{0, 1,2, 3\}$, where:

- $0$ : No $65$'s show up
- $1$ : One $65$ shows up
- $2$ : Two $65$'s show up
- $3$ : One $6$ shows up

If we define $p: \mathbb{X} \times \mathbb{X} \rightarrow [0,1]$ as
$$
p(x,y) = \mathbb{P}[X_{n+1} = y | X_n = x]
$$

then for $a \in \{0,1\}$:

$$
p(a, b) = \begin{cases} \frac{35}{36}, \quad a = b \\
\frac{1}{36}, \quad b = a + 1 \\
0, \quad \text{elsewise}
\end{cases}
$$
as the probability for a $65$ to show up after two successive rolls is $\frac{1}{36}$.

For $a=2$:

$$
p(a, b) = \begin{cases} \frac{5}{6}, \quad a = b \\
\frac{1}{6}, \quad b = a + 1 \\
0, \quad \text{elsewise}
\end{cases}
$$
as the probability for a $6$ to show up after one roll is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Considering the above, the **transition matrix** is:
$$ P = 
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{35}{36} & \frac{1}{36} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{35}{36} & \frac{1}{36} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

Does this chain describe the game correctly?

Comment: If the chain is in state $1$ and $65$ doesn't show up, the chain goes to state $0$; it doesn't stay in state $1$.

Comment: Oh sure, my bad. Does alternating the $\frac{35}{36}$ and $\frac{5}{6}$ with the $0$ in the second and third row fix it?

Comment: Not sure I understand; I posted answer.  BTW, the singular is "die", not "dice".

Comment: My answer was wrong.  Please uncheck it so I can delete it.

Comment: as sanity checks -- you should try to draw the state diagram associated with your game, and that of your matrix.  The former has a more states than the latter which is a problem.  Also try computing the expected time until pattern / absorbtion -- one way using the above matrix and some other way (I'd suggest using a renewal argument).  The expected values don't agree so they can't be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t model the game like this. If the first two rolls don’t yield $65$, they could still yield $X6$, and then you wouldn’t be back in the initial state, but in a different state in which a single $5$ would get you to the state where $65$ has occurred. You need a state for each prefix of the desired sequence, and thus six states; the corresponding transition matrix is

$$
P=\left[\matrix{
\frac56&\frac16&0&0&0&0\\
\frac46&\frac16&\frac16&0&0&0\\
\frac56&0&0&\frac16&0&0\\
\frac46&\frac16&0&0&\frac16&0\\
\frac56&0&0&0&0&\frac16\\
0&0&0&0&0&1
}\right]\;.
$$

Since the later states form a simple chain, you can combine some of them if you like, but you can’t combine the first two like you did, since they can be reached separately from other states.

Comment: Another difficulty with the OP’s proposed model is that some of the transition represent an unknown number of die rolls.